# My issue was resolved, but not because the question itself was answered. What do I do with the question?

Tags: discussion

I had a question on SO, the core of which was getting in my way of solving a particular problem. A commenter alerted me of an alternative way, which worked, but the alternative solution does not in any way answer the actual question. The question was "Why do I get this error using X?" and the current solution *for me* turned out to be "Use a slightly different method instead". But the original problem was never solved.

Now, I don't mind that the question itself was technically not answered - I mostly care about being able to solve my problems, whatever way that happens. I have nothing against workarounds or alternative solutions.

However, I now don't have any need for solving the problem that lead me to posting the question, and since it doesn't have an answer, should I delete the question? Or is there some other action that is more appropriate?

Comment: If doing it a "slightly different" way solves your problem then that's a valid answer.  Anybody else that runs into the same problem should also do it a slightly different way.  Just post it yourself and mark it as the answer.

Comment: Normally, I would have done that - but the question pertains to a mysterious overflow in a numerical datatype. In my particular case, I can work around that by not using a numerical datatype (the solution posed in comments) - which is not necessarily the case - and arguably, *probably* not the case - for others who have the same problem.

Comment: As long as it is "mysterious" you should surely just leave the question open then.  Somebody might show up a year from now and solve the mystery.